# Angular SPA on Firebase hosting with static welcome page for a new-user load-time performance

Tags: angular, firebase, performance, hosting

We're hosting an Angular SPA using firebase. Our firebase.json, partial, looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    ...,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/es/**",
        "destination": "/es/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/en/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "i18n": {
      "root": "/"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

This being an SPA, there is an initial performance hit for new users (due to time it takes to download the SPA bundle). While we continue to work on improving the initial load performance, as a quick solution, we would like to show users a static html file (say welcome.html) when they land on our site (for example: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). This being a static file, this would load quickly without needing to load the entire app. This static html in turn would have a link to the app's home page (for example: [www.example.com/home](http://www.example.com/home)) that would load the app.

So, in essence, when users come to our site with just the domain name and no path, we would like to return the content of welcome.html static file. For reasons mentioned, we cannot do this routing in the angular app, but it has to be done in firebase.json. I was playing with firebase.json *rewrites*, but could not get it correct. For example, I tried this and it didn't work:

```
{
  "hosting": {
   ...,
  "rewrites": [
    {
       "source": "/",
       "destination": "/en/welcome.html"
    },
    {
       "source": "/es/**",
       "destination": "/es/index.html"
    },
    {
       "source": "**",
       "destination": "/en/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "i18n": {
    "root": "/"
  }
},
...
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!

A combination of redirects and cleanUrls (optional) did the trick for me. For those that might be interested, here is the working configuration.

```
{
  "hosting": {
   ...,
  "redirects": [
    {
       "source": "/",
       "destination": "/en/welcome.html",
       "type": 301
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
       "source": "/es/**",
       "destination": "/es/index.html"
    },
    {
       "source": "**",
       "destination": "/en/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "i18n": {
    "root": "/"
  },
  "cleanUrls": true //This config is optional
},...
```