# Proper way to configure Firebase Hosting i18n with Angular SPA

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, internationalization, single-page-application

I am trying to configure Firebase to host an Angular SPA with several languages. I want to Firebase detect the preferred user language and serve its version to the user.

I have followed the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites) and it works perfect to serve the path "/" because it serves the index.html. If you start your navigation from the root it seems to work fine, but the problem comes when you refresh the page or enter a different path directly. It returns a 404.

My firebase.json looks like:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "website/dist",
        "i18n": {
            "root": "/localized-files"
        },
    ...
    },
    ...
}
```

My project structure is:

```
/website (Angular project)
    /dist (Compiled files)
         /localized-files
             /en_ALL
                 /assets
                 index.html
             /es_ALL
                 /assets
                 index.html
             /it_ALL
                 /assets
                 index.html

    /src
    ...
```

The question is, how to configure that all paths to point to the proper index.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular SPA on Firebase hosting with static welcome page for a new-user load-time performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267030/angular-spa-on-firebase-hosting-with-static-welcome-page-for-a-new-user-load-tim)

Comment: No, @MarcAnthonyB I don not want to add a Welcome page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is facing the same problem, the solution is quite easy:

Just add this settings inside the `hosting` object:

```
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
```

Firebase should specify that this rule is going to rewrite to the index.html file in the proper i18n folder.

Comment: Does it thought? I don't think it does.
Per the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites#priority-order it says that normal rewrites (your answer) come after it has tried doing i18n rewrites (based on cookie/Accept-Language header/country IP).

I think that in your app at your dist root you have an index file too that is being served, not the i18n version.

Comment: Yes it does. Since I did this change, it worked for me.